# How to use delete[] when pointer outside memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

*Note that the question has been changed and no longer matches the answers*

I'm trying to create memory to hold a buffer of floats (here, 4 floats).
I've allocated the memory, and all the 4 values in the memory are zero.

The loop of course iterates 4 times, but the 4th time moves ptr to outside the memory that I've allocated. So at the end of the loop I move ptr back to where I allocated the memory, and use `delete[]`.

My question is: Is the entire 4-float buffer being deleted when I call `delete[]`? (this is obviously what I need!)

```
int inFramesToProcess = 4;
float *ptr = new float[inFramesToProcess]();

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < inFramesToProcess; ++i) {
        ptr++;
    }

    ptr -= inFramesToProcess;

delete[] ptr;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I 'delete\[\]' a pointer that points into an allocated array, but not to the start of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420329/can-i-delete-a-pointer-that-points-into-an-allocated-array-but-not-to-the-st)

Comment: If you know the length of the array at compile time, why not use a fixed-length array `float framearr[4];`?

Comment: ah, i don't - i was just setting it to 4 for the sake of simplicity here :)
it's for audio processing, so i won't know the size of the buffer until this code is processed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the pointer before you increment it.

```
int inFramesToProcess = 4;
float *ptr = new float[inFramesToProcess]();
float *ptr_copy = ptr;

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < inFramesToProcess; ++i) {
        ptr_copy++;
    }

delete[] ptr;
```

Or just don't use pointers for dynamic arrays, use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.  Then you don't have to worry about deleting.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You can **only** `delete` the value you get from `new`. Keep the original pointer.

#### General rule:

Try hard to avoid modifying pointers **at all times**, no matter how clever/professional/"brilliant" it looks. There's really no reason to (you're welcome to prove me wrong). Use subscripts instead; they're more readable and easier to debug, and they avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is brilliant. So do modify pointers. But keep the original one to delete if needed :)

Comment: @Vlad: May I ask what about it you deem to be "brilliant"?

Comment: Every part. It is easier to code, understand, faster than subscripts. If someone doesn't like it - there is Java :)

Comment: @Vlad: Easier to code: agreed. (That doesn't mean it's easier to debug, though -- that's the worst part.) Easier to understand: Disagree, though it can be subjective. Faster than subscripts: **completely disagree** [citation needed].

Comment: Simple fact - when using subscript you are calculating offset and getting a value. Using pointer arithmetic you are just getting the value (usually incrementing the pointer value in register). And noop is always faster than any op.

Comment: @Vlad: Something tells me you're forgetting about some things, esp. loop unrolling...

Comment: True, unrolling loop with subscript is easier for compiler. But I prefer to do it myself where necessary rather than letting compiler make my code bigger. Unrolling can easily harm performance. So... it all depends.

Comment: @Vlad: `I prefer to do it myself where necessary rather than letting compiler make my code bigger`... doesn't doing it yourself also make the code bigger?

Comment: thanks for all the responses! i edited my original code slightly, although i didn't realize people had responded already! (so quick, thanks!)

Comment: If i use

ptr -= inFramesToProcess;

this would have the same effect as copying the pointer, is that correct?

Does the delete[] call here free up the entire block of memory that new() allocated?

Comment: @Jimmy: Sure! Yes, it *would*, but no, you *shouldn't* do that -- it's just *asking* for a bug to come up down the road. Just keep the original pointer!

Comment: @Mehrdad: agree that pointer arithmetic can be abused and shouldn't be used everywhere, but there are some solid cases where it's super useful, the implementation of iterators is one that comes to mind...

Comment: @Darren: But in the case of iterators, the concept of a pointer no longer exists -- the iterators just *happen* to be pointers, but that's an abstracted away. So that doesn't count in my statement. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, what I'm saying is that if you want to *implement* an iterator (possibly for a custom container type, for example) you *may* need to do this using direct pointer arithmetic. Of course the users of your containers/iterators don't see the pointer manipulation.